# Which Stack Exchange site should I use?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which Stack Exchange should I use for cyber security questions or in other words, is there a Stack Exchange like Stack Overflow, but for ethical hackers?

In my case, I'm starting into the cybersec world and as a beginner I get to tons of difficulties and mostly errors with the linux ecosystem (Kali Linux) and more over with software that's related to cybersec.

EXAMPLE:

1. Having problems installing certain packages for "Kali Linux", like wifite2 or hashcat.
2. Getting errors no one in the tutorials is getting when installing a certain package which doesn't come with the OS...
3. Want to learn how a certain software is properly used "hashcat" for example.
4. Having difficulties understanding the way a certain software works..

Comment: There is also a networkwide search: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=kali+linux+hashcat

Comment: [Why are Kali questions hated so much?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5257/83513)

Comment: Why did I get -7 on my question? is it because people rated it as a bad question or have I made something wrong?

Comment: @WckD-qwerty If you check the tooltip at the downvote button, it says _"The question does not show any research effort ..."_ Apparently you failed about that miserably.

Comment: Should I delete the question then?

Comment: People are more liberal with their downvotes on meta, it can be anything from simple disagreement to lack of research or bad quality. That doesn't say much but you shouldn't fret about downvotes on meta, generally.

Answer (score 3):

You can find all the sites [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) and search for an appropriate one.

My suggestion based on the information you give would be [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Having said that please make sure to read [the help](https://security.stackexchange.com/help) before posting.

Addressing your example, not being able to install packages on Kali is a Linux issue, not an Information Security one, so that would go on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Quick one. What does SE stand for? "Special Edition"?

Comment: Sorry, "Stack Exchange"

Comment: per my reading, [kali tag at U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/kali-linux/info) suggests that beginner questions on this matter will likely get closed over there

Comment: @gnat I think the OP example was more of a package installation issue than a Kali specific one, it should be OK. You are not wrong though, I think "How do I do install Kali Linux" or "How do I use Kali?" style questions would get closed.